# Applescript screencapture second monitor

Tags: xcode, macos, applescript

I'd like to capture the whole screen of my second external monitor through Applescript. When I press CMD + SHIFT + 3 than I get two images from each monitor.

Any tips?

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 3):

Try to just remove the file for the first monitor:

```
screencapture monitor1.png monitor2.png;rm monitor1.png
```

`-m` only captures the main monitor but there is no option to specify another monitor:

```
$ screencapture -h
screencapture: illegal option -- h
usage: screencapture [-icMPmwsWxSCUtoa] [files]
  -c         force screen capture to go to the clipboard
  -C         capture the cursor as well as the screen. only in non-interactive m
odes
  -d         display errors to the user graphically
  -i         capture screen interactively, by selection or window
               control key - causes screen shot to go to clipboard
               space key   - toggle between mouse selection and
                             window selection modes
               escape key  - cancels interactive screen shot
  -m         only capture the main monitor, undefined if -i is set
  -M         screen capture output will go to a new Mail message
  -o         in window capture mode, do not capture the shadow of the window
  -P         screen capture output will open in Preview
  -s         only allow mouse selection mode
  -S         in window capture mode, capture the screen not the window
  -t<format> image format to create, default is png (other options include pdf, 
jpg, tiff and other formats)
  -T<seconds> Take the picture after a delay of <seconds>, default is 5
  -w         only allow window selection mode
  -W         start interaction in window selection mode
  -x         do not play sounds
  -a         do not include windows attached to selected windows
  -r         do not add dpi meta data to image
  -l<windowid> capture this windowsid
  -R<x,y,w,h> capture screen rect
  files   where to save the screen capture, 1 file per screen
```

Comment: +1 for figuring out from the poor `man` page how to even target *other* monitors: with additional, positional filename arguments. While there is no directly supported way to skip a monitor, there are two tricks: (a) use the same filename *twice*, relying on the files getting written *sequentially*, so that the last monitor targeted "wins" (though this an implementation detail one may not want to rely upon), (b) specify `/dev/null` as the first filename; while this works, the caveat is that an error message is reported and exit code is 1, making it difficult to detect actual failure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer...I found another solution in the meanwhile. Just use -RX,Y,W;H and take a negative X